# Unicode characters turn into question marks in Codeignter

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, unicode, odbc

I have a data with `VARCHAR2` data type in `database(oracle)` like this "`Mary’s`" but when I try to retrieve it using `codeigniter` it displays "`Mary?s`" It replaces the single quote with question mark(?). I'm also getting the same result with Chinese characters

The character set of my database is `AL32UTF8`.

I'm using `codeigniter` and `odbc driver`

Please help me to fix this problem

I already added this code in my view:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');?>
```

Here's my database configuration:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'      => "test",
    'hostname' => "",
    'username' => 'test'
    'password' => 'test123',
    'database' => 'myShop',
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf-8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt'  => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE,
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with the definition of the Oracle table and columns that you are inserting into. Are you using a `CHAR`/`VARCHAR2` column or an `NCHAR`/`NVARCHAR2` column? What is the character encoding used in the database? Can you store the data directly using SQL queries (without using Codeigniter) and does it work or do you get the same issues? If so, then the issue is likely with the character encoding in the database and if not then the issue is likely somewhere outside the database .... please do some debugging and narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering. I'm using varchar2 for the columns and the character encoding for the database is AL32UTF8. I can also store data directly using SQL queries.

Comment: Somehow set the environment variable NLS_LANG to ".AL32UTF8" (with leading full stop) in the process that invokes PHP.

Comment: Where can I set the NLS_LANG in codeigniter?

Comment: You really need to set it before the PHP process executes, so it would be in something like your web configuration files.  I list some places in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html) but it varies with OS distribution and web server versions.